# Unable to get innerhtml with JS

Tags: javascript

I have used visual basic and selenium to automate some tasks at work for a few years now and have very little experience with js. Right now, i am creating a browser extension for edge to copy some specific fields on the webpage and then paste those values onto another webpage. I can scrape these values using vba and selenium, but get no values using js.

This vba code does work to get the attribute I need.

```vb
Set elem = D.FindElementByCss("#MainContent_grdClassValues > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)")
   
txtstr = elem.Attribute("innerHTML")
        
MsgBox "" & txtstr & ""
```

This is the js code i tried and the extension debugger tells me it cannot read properties of null (reading ‘innerHTML’)

```js
document.getElementById(‘copybtn’).addEventListener(‘click’, function (){
  let val = document.querySelector(#MainContent_grdClassValues > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)”).innerHTML();
  alert(val);
});
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct characters for your syntax: Your single-quotes (`‘` and `’`) are U+2018 and U+2019, not the ASCII single-quote `'` U+0027. Similarly, your double-quote (`”`) is U+201d, not '"' U+0022.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `innerHTML` is a property of DOM-nodes, not a function. It should work if you change the querySelector line to

```js
let val = document.querySelector("#MainContent_grdClassValues > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)").innerHTML;
```

Also, you missed a qoute-mark at the start of your selector, but I presume that's just a typo in the question.

Comment: Yes, was a typo for the missing “.  I tried that line of code and im still getting the error saying it cant read properties of null. Is there anything special when doing this through a browser extension?  I can post that code as well if it would help. As i mentioned, if i open the page and use selenium and vba, it returns the attribute. Here, i click the copy button from my browser extension and get null.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with plugin development, but the error would suggest the element does not exist in the document. My hunch would be that, in the context of a plugin, `document` refers to some plugin specific context, instead of the page document you're trying to work with. There should be some information on this in the documentation for the browser you're developing for